# Problem in Reading ID3v2.3 tag?

Tags: c#, id3

I have a problem in reading an ID3v2.3 tag. First of all I read about id3 tags from www.id3.org. The documentation of id3 tags says it has first 3 bytes which contain 'ID3' then 2 bytes contain version and revision number(for example 03 00) & then next first byte contain flags(Unsynchronisation, Extended header, Experimental indicator) then next 4 bytes is reserverd for size. I am able to read size. But My problem is that when I seek my pointer from current position to forward direction (size which I have taken from ID3 tag size), so it means I have reaached at the end of ID3 tag, It means so next byte we will read is the MP3 data byte, but it is not case. So Help me in detecting MP3 header & MP3 data with the help of ID3 tag size. And My second question is that Is MP3 frames are mixed with ID3 frames or Is it completely seprate from ID3 tag. If it is seprate from ID3 tag so in the end of ID3 tag there is a first MP3 frame. Is is right or not? Tell me

Comment: Have you checked out taglib btw? There's a C# port here: http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/taglib-sharp/src/TagLib/Id3v2/

Comment: Did you click the link? You'll see .cs files.

Comment: Just take note that a lot of tag writers will allocate more space than they need so when you make changes to the tag you won't need to rewrite the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you incorrectly read the size? The four size bytes have their leftmost bit zeroed. This leaves one with only 28 bits. Taken from the ID3.org documentation:

> "The ID3v2 tag size is encoded with
>   four bytes where the most
>   significant bit (bit 7) is set to zero
>   in every byte, making a total    of 28
>   bits. The zeroed bits are ignored, so
>   a 257 bytes long tag is    represented
>   as $00 00 02 01."

ie. 00000000 00000000 00000010 00000001
becomes
        0000 00000000 00000001 00000001

This was probably the most confusing thing for me in regards to the tags, so perhaps it caught you off guard as well.

Answer (score 1):

MP3 frames at not mixed with ID3 frames. Please note that in ID3v2.x tag header size value is an synchronization safe integer, which is essentially an integer converted into a format in which the MSB of each byte is 0. It is equivalent to insert one 0 after each 7 bits. Read in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchsafe

Also you can have a look at here: [Synchronization Safe Integer](http://phoxis.org/2010/05/08/synch-safe/)

In the below link you can find an overview of the ID3 Tag system and also a manual description on how to decode the ID3 Tags: [What are ID3 Tags all about?](http://phoxis.org/2010/05/08/what-are-id3-tags-all-about/#hacktag)